# How to activate the Tab from the Javascript Console below?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome, console, chromium

I'm using Chrome's javascript console (If you're using Chrome or Chromium, you can just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> now to open it) below the current opened tab.

Is there something I can enter *into* the console so that the document in the tab above gets the focus and the console looses the focus?

I tried with

```
chrome.tabs
```

but it only gives

```
undefined
```

Comment: I heard that you wanted to skyrocket this question, so here's a small push :)

Comment: Thanks, in an hour I can put a bounty on this, so not that other users think it's just a slacking question. I can imagine that this is not easy to answer as one might think firsthand that it is not possible and to answer it one needs to know Google Chrome / Chromium pretty well to actually *know* if it is possible or not.

Comment: You probably already found the [chrome.tabs docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html) in the Chrome extension library, seems `chrome.tabs` is restricted to be used by extension code. If you enter "chrome" in the console, you'll get all properties available from console. Will see if I can find a workaround.

Comment: @SaschaM78: Yes I found that (and used in an extension already ;)) that `chrome.tabs`. Would be great to see if there's a workaround.

Comment: That's a neat shortcut. I'm curious why would one want to type an exit command instead of closing the terminal with Ctrl-Shift-J?

Comment: @NoBugs: By pasting some test-code in there that would execute that automatically having the tab *active* and with *focus*, I was looking for that to validate if cuzrsor-positioning inside a textbox worked.

Comment: Will pasting as a `javascript:function(){...` url work?

Comment: @NoBugs: Yes, but the javascript code to close the console is missing in your example. If you have one, post it as an answer below and grab the bounty ;)

Comment: Check my answer below please, it seems everyone is ignoring the fact that you want to use chrome.tabs.  It requires you set permissions in the extensions manifest to enable.  See answer.

Answer (score 8):

https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=157179

says

(<kbd>F6</kbd> ) Or (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>)

but you'll have to switch through bunch of things before you reach the main webcontent.

Comment: With *"enter into the console"* I actually meant do type javascript code in there and pressing enter ;) - But the hotkey is welcomed anyway, thanks for the hint.

Comment: FWIW, I have found half an answer.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html

Comment: That is for extenstions, they can access `chrome.tabs` if the user allowed it (the extension asks to get the permissions when installed).

Answer (score 6):

The only way to gain focus without closing the console would be to call either `alert();`, `confirm();` or `prompt();`.
Alternatively by closing the console (`window.open("javascript:close()","_self");`) , the main tab can gain focus.

Comment: This actually works with `alert()`, `confirm()` or `prompot()` but has the side-effect of having that message box there. So it does not focus the tab *but* those message-boxes. Anyway, thanks for suggesting that.  Calling `window.open("javascript:close()","_self")` does not give me much of an effect though.

Comment: Awared for the most creative answer so far.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Firebug's Command Line API* wikipage](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API), there is no way; it will only output data about the, ahem, inputs.

*which is what the Javascript Console uses

Comment: Even this is a nice hint about Firebug (and potentially Chrome), this must not mean that there is nothing in addition that can do so in Google Chrome. Just noting. Thanks for the link anyway, I was not aware of that API.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call this an elegant solution in any way whatsoever, but as a hack, it'll do the job.

Your question is "how to give focus to the main document *from* the Chrome Console"; with that, I'm throwing in a middle-element - a popup window. The idea is, if you can create a popup window that self-closes (from the Console), when it closes the focus goes back to the parent window. In this case, it's the actual document you were on, not the Console in Chrome.

Here's the full code laid-out:

```
var openScript = document.createElement('script');
openScript.innerHTML = 'openWindow = window.open(""); openWindow.document.write(\'<script>window.close();</script>\');';
document.body.appendChild(openScript);
```

This code can be collapsed into a one-liner that can be copy+pasted into the console and, after you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> it will popup, close, and give focus back to the original document. Whatever element on the page had focus before you gave focus to the console, or whatever element you changed focus to *in* the console (via `document.getElementById('something').focus()`, or similar), will gain focus on the page.

The caveat to this approach is that the website you use this on needs to have popups enabled. Alternatively, and not really recommended, you could just "enable all popups" in Chrome.

As an added extra, if you're going to use this multiple times on the same page (without refreshing), you could wrap the javascript that's added to the page in a function call and just call that function each time. For instance:

```
...
openScript.innerHTML = 'function refocus() { openWindow = window.open(""); openWindow.document.write(\'<script>window.close();</script>\'); }';
...
```

Then just call `refocus();` whenever you want to give focus back to the parent. Of course, if you leave the current page for any reason you would need to re-run the full block of code again.

For what it's worth, if you see yourself using this a lot, you could also add the extension [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) and save this block of code into a function there; then, you'd never need to worry about running the whole thing each time - you would just call the function name you saved.

One-liner from above (for easy copy+paste):

```
var openScript = document.createElement('script'); openScript.innerHTML = 'openWindow = window.open(""); openWindow.document.write(\'<script>window.close();</script>\');'; document.body.appendChild(openScript);
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of pasting code in console:

```
var a = function() {my code...}; a()
```

You can paste and run it from the url bar:

```
javascript:var a = function() {alert('hi');}; a()
```

You can even add this javascript: url as a bookmark, this is how many code snippets ('bookmarklets') are run.

Comment: Don't wanna stop your motivation here, but an answer suggesting `alert()` does alread exists. And technically it's not an answer (as already commented), because it gives the focus to the alert box, not the tab. I need the focus in the tab.